# I am not able to push files in to my sdcard

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, ddms

Please tell me  steps - how to go to AVD Manager and select your AVD then Click on Edit and in the Hardware add SDCard Support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

step1:

select window and go for Android Virtual Device Manager

[image]

Next step for editing or creating For creating go for create New

[image]

It will appear window..For editing choose  avd and click edit and assign the sd card support option..

[image]

[image]
For selecting push in sd card go to DDMS option click file explorer

```
c:\android-sdk\platform-tools\>abd remount
```

follow the link below

[link](http://daraizetechnologies.blogspot.in/2011/06/how-to-mount-sdcard-in-android-emulator.html)

Comment: I have an issue that when i try to push files to my sdcard i get an error [2013-01-24 12:53:27 - ddms] transfer error: Read-only file system
[2013-01-24 12:53:27] Failed to push selection: Read-only file system
do you have any idea

Comment: @Anu0042 did you create Avd with sd card support

Comment: @Anu0042 did you try it..

Comment: ya i did it bit the issue stands the same. i have added permission in my code.

Comment: @Anu0042 check the link..now

Comment: @Anu0042 did you get any result

Comment: yes sorry i was out for some time. But that is not the proper sdcard. The sdcard is in mnt file. My issue was same i was trying to insert into sdcard in this image. Thanks a lot.